# array.length returns number of strings instead of number of array elements

Tags: javascript

Simple javascript that is supposed to alert the number of array elements.

```
var name = ["Bill", "Kevin", "Alice"];
alert(name.length)
```

But when I run the code it will alert the number of strings in the name array. Also if I alert name[1] it will alert i instead of Kevin. If I change the name of the array to something else, ex. friendsNames, it functions as intended. What is it about the variable "name" that changes the behavior?

Comment: May be you have another Variable, name already as Strings

Comment: `name` is also a predefined global variable - use with caution.

Comment: I'm not seeing what you're seeing http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/HsJW2/. I also don't understand the title of your question. What else should length be giving you?

Comment: I wrote the code above in a html file and ran it in chrome.  alert(name.length) should alert 3 since there are 3 array elements in the array name but chrome is alerting 14.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The global object in browsers is `window` and any top-level `var` statements will behave as if you were doing this:

```
window.name = ["Bill", "Kevin", "Alice"];
alert(name[1]);
```

In this case [`window.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.name) has a getter and a setter that convert the value to a string. That means that you essentially have this:

```
window.name = ["Bill", "Kevin", "Alice"].toString();
// = "Bill,Kevin,Alice"
alert(name[1]);
```

The quick answer is that this is a good reason not to execute code in the top scope:

```
(function(){
    var name = ["Bill", "Kevin", "Alice"];
    alert(name[1]);
})();
```

or don't use `name` in the global scope:

```
var personNames = ["Bill", "Kevin", "Alice"];
alert(personNames[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

`var name` in the global namespace is essentially [`window.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.name) (any variables declared in the global namespace belong to the `window` object), which can be used to get/set the name of the window. `window.name` needs to be a string and so the array is being implicitly converted to a string when you assign a value to it.

If you logged `name`, you would see `Bill,Kevin,Alice`. The length of this string is `16`, which is what you are seeing.

If you don't want this behavior, you can declare `name` in the local scope of a function:

```
(function() {
    var name = ["a", "b", "c"];
    console.log(name.length); //should log 3 instead of 5
}();
```

It is always better to wrap your code inside a function or an IIFE since the DOM exposes many global variables that you may unintentionally overwrite to cause bizarre behavior. Enclosing your code inside an IIFE also stops you from polluting the global namespace.